# Get result from two different tables using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have the following two tables 
1st table is students

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| tag_id   |     name   | colloge     |  department| class  |dev_id|
|----------+------------+-------------+------------+--------+------|
| 00000022 | Jhon Rayan | Engineering |  Computer  | first  | c01  | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

2nd table is called lecture_table

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| dev_tag| lecture_name| lecturer_name|  start | end   |
|--------+-------------+--------------+--------+-------|
| c01    | Math I      | Jhon Simone  |  08:30 | 10:30 | 
--------------------------------------------------------
```

So i need to make a query by tag_id(00000022) in students table and get full information about it from students table.then compare this student through (dev_id) with lecture_table (dev_tag) to get the lecture associated to this student only from whole lecture_table
i tried to use this query but didn't work

```
    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT s.tag_id
    s.dev_id,
    s.name,
    s.colloge,
    s.class,
    lt.lecture_name
    ,lt.lecturer_name,
    lt.dev_tag,lt.day,
    lt.start,lt.end,
    FROM students s INNER JOIN lecture_table lt ON s.dev_id = lt.dev_tag WHERE s.tag_id LIKE '%".$query."%' AND(`name` LIKE '%".$_SESSION['username']."%')")  or die(mysql_error());
```

so any one can help??

Comment: The solution seems to be correct only a few syntactic failures there are, like a , before FROM statement or missing , after s.tag_id

Comment: are getting some error?? would you mind posting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modify your query as**

```
$raw_results = mysql_query(
     "SELECT s.tag_id, s.dev_id, s.name, s.colloge, s.class, 
         lt.lecture_name ,lt.lecturer_name, lt.dev_tag,lt.day,
         lt.start,lt.end
       FROM students s JOIN lecture_table lt ON s.dev_id = lt.dev_tag 
       WHERE s.tag_id LIKE '%".$query."%' 
         AND(`name` LIKE '%".$_SESSION['username']."%')")  
      or die(mysql_error());
```

Remove **`,`** before From keyword and place a **`,`** after **`SELECT s.tag_id`**

Comment: OK its work now my friend am so annoyed cause i didn't see (,) in my query and i will submit your answer